# clang: error: unknown argument: '-n' from libtool on macos

Tags: xcode, clang, libtool

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  all-am                                                                          
/bin/sh ./libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=link /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/g++  -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk -I/Users/unhammer/src/macdivvun-service/Dependencies
/Static/x86_64/include -fvisibility=hidden -std=c++1z  -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk -L/Users/unhammer/src/macdivvun-service/Dependencies/Static/x86_64/lib -o hfst-ospell main.o lib
hfstospell.la -n  -L/usr/local/lib -licui18n -licuuc -licudata                                                                           
libtool: link: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/g++ -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk -I/Users/unhammer/src/macdivvun-service/Dependencies/Static/x86_64/include -fvisi
bility=hidden -std=c++1z -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk -o hfst-ospell main.o -n -Wl,-bind_at_load  -L/Users/unhammer/src/macdivvun-service/Dependencies/Static/x86_64/lib ./.libs/lib
hfstospell.a -L/usr/local/lib -licui18n -licuuc -licudata                                                                                
clang: error: unknown argument: '-n'                                                                                                     
make[1]: *** [hfst-ospell] Error 1                                                                                                       
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Where does that `-n` come from? How can I find out? I'm using `xcodebuild`, but `xcodebuild -showBuildSettings -scheme Dependencies|grep -e -n` gives nothing, and I see no `-n` in any of the flags in Makefile.am or configure.ac in the actual (autotools) project.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the actual goal being built in the *generated* `Makefile`, starting from the line `$(AM_V_CXXLD)$(hfst_ospell_LINK) $(hfst_ospell_OBJECTS) $(hfst_ospell_LDADD) $(LIBS)`
and manually checked all the variables there recursively. Finally, I saw that `LIBS` had `-n  -L/usr/local/lib -licui18n -licuuc -licudata`. And `LIBS` was `LIBS = @LIBS@` in `Makefile.in`, so set by `configure.ac`, which ran `icu-config --ldflags` to set it.

For some reason, the version (57.1) of `icu-config --ldflags` that I had gave `-n  -L/usr/local/lib -licui18n -licuuc -licudata` instead of `-L/usr/local/lib -licui18n -licuuc -licudata`. Upgrading icu solved it.